# How to load the value to input after onchange function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

Good day, i have a dropdown that when is selected it must populate the value to the input using `data-id` because i'm already using the `id` for something else. Please note that the data are populated to the dropdown `select`.

Here is the `input` and `select`

```
<input type="text" id="@appConfig.Id" data-id="WarehouseInput" data-itemType="int" name="@appConfig.Name" class="form-control" required />

 <select type="text" value="SelectWarehouse" name="@appConfig.Name" id="SelectWarehouse" data-itemType="int" class="selectpicker show-tick  form-control" data-live-search="true"></select>
```

When the when the dropdown is selected it need to populate the value on `input`

```
$(function () {
$("#SelectWarehouse").change(function () {

    var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr("data-id", "WarehouseInput");
   // var inputid = document.getElementById("WarehouseInput");
    //alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
});});
```

Comment: `selectedValue` on javascript funtion come back with the value that i want to populate is to `input` so i want to call the input using the `data-id` which is `WarehouseInput`  @Lewis

Comment: Maybe `$("[data-id='WarehouseInput']").val()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
   $("#SelectWarehouse").change(function (e) {
       $('[data-id="WarehouseInput"]').val(e.target.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Good day, the selectedText is coming back with the value but it is not populating to the `input WarehouseInput`

Comment: Does your input added dynamically?

Comment: No, its static @Hikmat

Comment: add this to change callback, see if it prints the input: console.log($('[data-id="WarehouseInput"]'))